# Using inet_ntop from libevent

Tags: c, sockets, libevent

I implement echo server given in the [libevent book](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref8_listener.html).

I modify `accept_conn_cb` function so that the server prints the IPv4 address of a newly created connection (in decimal dot notation). The following is my callback

```
static void accept_conn_cb(
  struct evconnlistener *listener,
  evutil_socket_t fd, 
  struct sockaddr *address, 
  int socklen,
  void *ctx)
{
   char ipAddress[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

   struct sockaddr_in * saddr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) &address;

   if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(saddr_in->sin_addr), ipAddress, INET_ADDRSTRLEN))
      puts("Couldn't retrieve IPv4 address");

   printf("A new connection established from %s\n", ipAddress);

   /* ... */
```

When I compile and run it it always prints the follwoing strange addresses:

A new connection established from **252.127.0.0** or

A new connection established from **253.127.0.0** or

A new connection established from **255.127.0.0**

no matter from what machine I connect. I use telnet for testing connections.

I have written another version of an echo server written in pure C (without libevent).When I run it it always returns the right address.

Comment: I have successfully retrieved the remote address using `getpeername`, but still wonder why `inet_ntop` does not work. It seems something  wrong with `address ` parameter of the callback.

Comment: You are passing in "address" as a pointer to a sockaddr structure (although it is probably a pointer to a sockaddr_in).  Then you are "casting" it as a pointer to a sockaddr_in... (i.e. saddr_in)... BUT you are taking the ADDRESS of it instead of "address" itself...   Instead of saddr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) &address;  You should be doing saddr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)   address;  (Note NO ampersand).

Comment: @TonyB you are right. Worked.